# Heroku + Django migrate command doesn’t create any table

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, postgis

As I know when running 
$heroku run python manage.py migrate

it creates all tables from models.py. But my output looks different: the table wasn’t created or even mentioned.

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: findCharge

Running migrations:
  Applying findCharge.0001_initial... OK
  Applying findCharge.0002_auto_20161124_1729... OK
  Applying findCharge.0003_auto_20161124_1955... OK
  Applying findCharge.0004_chargepoints_description... OK
```

Anyway when I call

```
$ heroku pg:psql and then ONYX=> \dt
```

It looks like the table was created and “findCharge_chargepoints” in list of relations.

```
…
public | findCharge_chargepoints | table | owner_name
…
```

But when I type

```
ONYX=> SELECT * FROM findCharge_chargepoints;
ERROR:  relation "findcharge_chargepoints" does not exist
```

I was trying to run “python manage.py migrate” without app name, but result was the same. I run “makemigrations” on my local machine before pushing to git. I also was able to create superuser and I can open https://my-app-name.herokuapp.com/admin and add some data to db, but my app doesn’t see this data.

Any suggestions? I’m sticking in it for 3 days now so I will be grateful for any help.

P.S. I use heroku postgresql hobby-basic with postgis extension.

P.P.S.

database settings from settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default':{
    'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'charging_points',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
}
}
```

and at the end of the file

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default']['ENGINE'] = "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis"
```

Comment: Can you show the DATABASE settings?

Comment: If it doesn't use the default 'public' schema then you may also have to provide the full `schema.table` path.

Comment: Daniel Roseman, I've just added this info to the question if it can help.

Comment: @shongololo Since I'm quite new in heroku I'm wondering if I did it right. I used command: SET search_path TO findCharge_chargepoints,public; but anyway when I'm trying to do something with the table I'm getting error: table "findcharge_chargepoints" does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I found the solution or a kind of solution. The table was created but to get access to it I have to use double-quotes:

```
select * from "findCharge_chargepoints";
```

I didn't expect it 'cause other tables created by migrate (like auth_user, auth_group etc.) don't need any qoutes at all.

Comment: That is because you have an upper case character there... the "C" in **C**harge. if you dont put double quotes, it may look for `findcharge_chargepoints` (notice the lowercase "c" in charge). When you put double quotes you state explicity the name of your table and the upper/lowercase.

Comment: Thanks @Sharky, now I see it.

Comment: To clarify, since the behavior was a little non-obvious to me: PostgreSQL identifiers are technically case sensitive, but when an _unquoted_ identifier is used in DML or DDL, PostgreSQL implicitly lower cases it. So, `select * from AUTH_USER` is processed as `select * from auth_user` and works fine, since the table name is "auth_user" (not "AUTH_USER"). If you did `select * from "AUTH_USER"`, however, the query will fail. So whatever created your `findCharge_chargepoints` table did so with quoted identifiers and thus explicit case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

just run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```